# Trying to capture repeating blocks of text with regular expression (in c#)

Tags: c#, regex, text

I have large text files that all look like this :

```
   001 00 *f a *a 0 014 017 1 *d 19740918 *c 19890127 *b 718500
    004 00 *a e *r c
    008 00 *t m *v 1 *u f *a 1974 *b dk *l dan
    009 00 *a a *g xx
    021 00 *a 87-7492-095-2 *d kr 69.00
    032 00 *a DBR197075
    041 00 *a dan *d eng
    100 00 *a Kêœ³rsted *h Tage
    245 00 *a Storbritannien og Danmark 1914-1920
    260 00 *b Odense Universitetsforlag *c 1974
    300 00 *a 240 sider *b ill
    440 00 *a Odense University studies in history and social sciences *v 17
    534 00 *a Med engelsk resumÃ©
    652 00 *m 93.6
    652 00 *Ã¥ 1 *p 96.7
    710 00 *a Odense Universitet *x se *w Odense University studies in history and social sciences
    e01 00 *a illegal subfield x present in 710
    e01 00 *a illegal subfield w present in 710

    001 00 *f a *a 0 014 573 4 *d 19741030 *c 19871230 *b 718500
    004 00 *a e *r c
    008 00 *t m *v 1 *u u *a 1974 *b dk *l dan
    009 00 *a a *g xx
    021 00 *a 87-422-7944-5 *d kr 49.00
    032 00 *a DBR197075 *x NDF190104
    245 00 *a De Â¤politiske partier *Ã¸ Ved Poul MÃ¸ller
    250 00 *a Ny udgave *c redigeret af \Poul MÃ¸ller\ *d udgivet af Socialpolitisk Forening
    260 00 *b Det Danske Forlag *c 1974
    440 00 *a Nyt socialt bibliotek
    652 00 *m 32.26
    700 00 *a MÃ¸ller *h Poul *c f. 1919
    710 00 *a Socialpolitisk Forening *x se *w Nyt socialt bibliotek
    e01 00 *a illegal subfield x present in 710
    e01 00 *a illegal subfield w present in 710

    001 00 *f a *a 0 014 691 9 *d 19741030 *c 19871018 *b 718500
    004 00 *a e *r c
    008 00 *t m *v 1 *u f *a 1973 *b dk *l dan
    009 00 *a a *g xx
    021 00 *a 87-7472-020-1 *d kr 27.60
    032 00 *a DBR197075
    110 00 *a Landsarkivet for SjÃ¦lland m. m
    245 00 *a Oversigt over Landsarkivets samling af kort og tegninger indtil ca. 1900
    260 00 *c 1973
    300 00 *a 6, 207 sider
    440 00 *a ForelÃ¸bige arkivregistraturer / udgivet af Landsarkivet for SjÃ¦lland m. m.
    652 00 *m 02.91
    710 00 *a Landsarkivet for SjÃ¦lland m. m. *x se *w ForelÃ¸bige arkivregistraturer / udgivet af Landsarkivet for SjÃ¦lland m. m.
    e01 00 *a illegal subfield x present in 710
    e01 00 *a illegal subfield w present in 710
```

I need to capture every group so that I can process them separately for errors.

Every group starts with "001" and ends at the next empty line (so I have three groups in the example above).

Did a bit of testing on http://regexstorm.net/ using naive patterns like 001((.|\n)*)(?=001) but never got it to work. I have never used RegEx before and I must admit it looks a bit hard to use, but from what I've heard this is the way to go when breaking up semi-complicated text files.

There is obviously something wrong with the text encoding. So some of the text is garbled and god knows how things like newline and endofline looks like (Notepad++ says CRLF).

The Regular Expression should go something like this :

Match all groups of text that starts with "001" and end just before the next "001" or at the first empty line.

Most text files have about 50000+ such groups.

I'm am using c# so any suggestions in that language would be nice, but I consider that a luxury and I understand that most Regular expressions can be used in every language that supports them with little to no modification

Any help would be appreciated :)

Tia.

Comment: To be honest, sometimes I avoid Regex due to its complexity, and sometimes it isn't necessarily any faster/easier to use than other methods. For this, you could simply use a `StringBuilder` object, and append to it until hitting the next `001`. The `StreamReader` class also has `ReadLine`, however I'm not sure how that would behave with text like that.

Comment: I've been parsing text like this for 40 years.  Not very difficult in c#.  If you don't get a satisfactory answer I will work on it in a few hours.

Comment: With huge files using regex doesn't make a lot of sense since the entire file get pulled into memory at one time slowing down processing an d using alot of memory.

Answer (score 0):

You could just try

```
.Split(new string[] { "\r\n001" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

It's probably easier than regexes.

Comment: What kind of  *char*  is this `'\r\n001'`

Comment: Test it before posting even if you are sure about what you have posted

Comment: @Eser I'm not familiar with C#. What split am I looking for?

Comment: `.Split(new[] { "str1","str2" },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`

Comment: @Eser Thanks, I was having trouble finding it b/c SO doesn't let you search for `#`

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use a regex, it would go something like this:

```
(?s)\b001\b.*?(?:\n\s*?\n|$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sA2wK0/2)

- `(?s)`: activate `RegexOptions.Singleline` (you can omit it if you include this flag in the pattern options)
- `\b001\b`: `001` as a whole word, `\b` is a word boundary
- `.*?`: anything (ungreedy match, try to get as few characters as possible
- Either:

  - `\n\s*?\n`: a newline followed by optional whitespace then another newline
  - `$`: or the end of the string

Phew. That regex isn't *that* complicated, but maybe your code would be simpler if you did line-by-line processing:

- start when `line.TrimStart().StartsWith("001 ")`, or match it against `^\s*001\b`
- stop when you get `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)`

Parsers are often implemented as state machines, and this fits the scheme.
That seems simpler to me, plus you avoid having to load the whole thing into memory at once :)

Answer (score 0):

You could go for:

```
^001           # look for 001 at the very beginning of a line
(?s:.+?)(?=^$) # turn on the single line mode
               # match anything lazily
               # make sure the positive lookahead (?=) matches an empty line
```

In `multiline` mode, see [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/rF7nZ1/1) (and mind the different modifiers!)

Answer (score 0):

`CR` is `\r` and `LF` is `\n` in C#.

If we use double end line as the delimiter it would work like this

```
string[] delimiter = new string[] {"\r\n\r\n"};
string[] SplitString = s.Split(delimiter, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Where `s` is the initial huge string.
The result is an string array where each element is a string starting with `001` and ending with `\r\n\r\n` (Double end line).

Answer (score 0):

Here is very simple solution provided each group starts following a blank line.  I can provide better solution if needed.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApplication85
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string inputLine = "";
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            List<string> group = null;
            while ((inputLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                inputLine = inputLine.Trim();
                if (inputLine.Length == 0)
                {
                    if (group != null)
                    {
                        ProcessData(group);
                        group = null;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (group == null)
                    {
                        group = new List<string>();
                    }
                    group.Add(inputLine);
                }
            }
            //process last group if there wasn't a blank line at end of group
            if (group != null) ProcessData(group);

        }
        static void ProcessData(List<string> data)
        {
            int a = 0;
        }

    }
}
```

Here is a solution where a new line isn't between the groups

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApplication85
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string inputLine = "";
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            List<string> group = null;
            while ((inputLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                inputLine = inputLine.Trim();
                Boolean newGroup = inputLine.StartsWith("001 ");
                if ((inputLine.Length == 0) || newGroup)
                {
                    if (group != null)
                    {
                        ProcessData(group);
                        group = null;
                    }
                    if (newGroup)
                    {
                        group = new List<string>();
                        group.Add(inputLine);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (group == null)
                    {
                        group = new List<string>();
                    }
                    group.Add(inputLine);
                }
            }
            //process last group if there wasn't a blank line at end of group
            if (group != null) ProcessData(group);

        }
        static void ProcessData(List<string> data)
        {
            int a = 0;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One regex way to solve the question:

```
        string body = @"""001 00 *f a *a 0 014 017 1 *d 19740918 *c 19890127 *b 718500
004 00 *a e *r c
008 00 *t m *v 1 *u f *a 1974 *b dk *l dan
009 00 *a a *g xx
021 00 *a 87-7492-095-2 *d kr 69.00
032 00 *a DBR197075
041 00 *a dan *d eng
100 00 *a Kêœ³rsted *h Tage
245 00 *a Storbritannien og Danmark 1914-1920
260 00 *b Odense Universitetsforlag *c 1974
300 00 *a 240 sider *b ill
440 00 *a Odense University studies in history and social sciences *v 17
534 00 *a Med engelsk resumÃ©
652 00 *m 93.6
652 00 *Ã¥ 1 *p 96.7
710 00 *a Odense Universitet *x se *w Odense University studies in history and social sciences
e01 00 *a illegal subfield x present in 710
e01 00 *a illegal subfield w present in 710

001 00 *f a *a 0 014 573 4 *d 19741030 *c 19871230 *b 718500
004 00 *a e *r c
008 00 *t m *v 1 *u u *a 1974 *b dk *l dan
009 00 *a a *g xx
021 00 *a 87-422-7944-5 *d kr 49.00
032 00 *a DBR197075 *x NDF190104
245 00 *a De Â¤politiske partier *Ã¸ Ved Poul MÃ¸ller
250 00 *a Ny udgave *c redigeret af \Poul MÃ¸ller\ *d udgivet af Socialpolitisk Forening
260 00 *b Det Danske Forlag *c 1974
440 00 *a Nyt socialt bibliotek
652 00 *m 32.26
700 00 *a MÃ¸ller *h Poul *c f. 1919
710 00 *a Socialpolitisk Forening *x se *w Nyt socialt bibliotek
e01 00 *a illegal subfield x present in 710
e01 00 *a illegal subfield w present in 710

001 00 *f a *a 0 014 691 9 *d 19741030 *c 19871018 *b 718500
004 00 *a e *r c
008 00 *t m *v 1 *u f *a 1973 *b dk *l dan
009 00 *a a *g xx
021 00 *a 87-7472-020-1 *d kr 27.60
032 00 *a DBR197075
110 00 *a Landsarkivet for SjÃ¦lland m. m
245 00 *a Oversigt over Landsarkivets samling af kort og tegninger indtil ca. 1900
260 00 *c 1973
300 00 *a 6, 207 sider
440 00 *a ForelÃ¸bige arkivregistraturer / udgivet af Landsarkivet for SjÃ¦lland m. m.
652 00 *m 02.91
710 00 *a Landsarkivet for SjÃ¦lland m. m. *x se *w ForelÃ¸bige arkivregistraturer / udgivet af Landsarkivet for SjÃ¦lland m. m.
e01 00 *a illegal subfield x present in 710
e01 00 *a illegal subfield w present in 710""";

        var pattern = @"(\s*001[\s\S]+?)(?=[^\n]+001\s+|$)";
        var result1 = Regex.Matches(body, pattern).Cast<Match>().ToList().ConvertAll(m => m.Groups[1].Value);
```